# Pyinstaller and wx

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, pyinstaller

i'm new to pyinstaller. I'm trying to build an application from some python scripts.
I have two scripts: interface.py and loadsave.py.
Following the tutorials i found i made it to the .spec file (nothing much, i know) then everything stops.
This is my interface.spec:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
a = Analysis(['interface.py','loadsave.py'],
             pathex=['/home/alessandro/Scrivania/tesi/ProgettoTesi_1'],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=None,
             runtime_hooks=None)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='interface',
          debug=False,
          strip=None,
          upx=False,
          console=False )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=None,
               upx=False,
               name='interface')
```

and the error when i try running `./interface` in the dist/interface/ directory

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "/home/alessandro/Scrivania/tesi/ProgettoTesi_1/build/interface/out00-PYZ.pyz/wx", line 45, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "/home/alessandro/Scrivania/tesi/ProgettoTesi_1/build/interface/out00-PYZ.pyz/wx._core", line 4, in <module>
ImportError: No module named _core_
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: I learned today of kivy, i'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to the hiddenimports in .spec file 'wx._core' or just _core.